# Excel macro to paste transpose based on repeated values in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

The first set of data is a snippet of may data (running into thousands of rows) in the first two columns.

The first column has repeated ticket numbers with different status. I want to have a unique row for each ticket and corresponding columns to have the various status(a transpose like). See below illustration:

```
Incident Number Measurement Status
INCIN0001910583 Detached
INCIN0001910583 Missed
INCIN0001908104 Detached
INCIN0001908104 Detached
INCIN0001908104 Missed
INCIN0001914487 Met
INCIN0001908444 Detached
INCIN0001908444 Detached
INCIN0001908444 Detached
INCIN0001908444 Met
INCIN0001910624 Met
INCIN0001910575 Detached
INCIN0001910575 Met
```

I'm looking for a macro (or formula) to achieve something like this:

```
INCIN0001910583 Detached    Missed      
INCIN0001908104 Detached    Detached    Missed  
INCIN0001914487 Met         
INCIN0001908444 Detached    Detached    Detached    Met
INCIN0001910624 Met         
INCIN0001910575 Detached    Met
```

As Tom pointed out, below is the recorded macro I have been using to achieve this, pasting the transpose in the first occurrence of the unique Incident Number(column A) and then manually removing the blanks.(however it takes ages to complete it for thousands of rows)

```
Sub transpose_paste()
'
' transpose_paste Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
    Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 14).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing site. Try putting something together based on the research you've done over the last few days. Worst comes to the worst - use the macro recorder and then come back.

Comment: Hi Tom, updated the query, been using this macro for sometime. However its almost same as doing it manually.  - Tony

Comment: So now remove all of the `ActiveWindow` statements - you don't need those. And combine the `Select` and `Paste` statement and you're starting to get somewhere. Now you probably need to turn this into a loop. Have a look into `for` loops and try and apply some logic around it. You will then be on your first steps to writing your first macro :) Once you've done all of that, if you're still having issues with it come back and update your post and I'm sure either myself or someone else will be very willing to help

Comment: see [this answer on superuser.](http://superuser.com/questions/998810/excel-duplicate-names-in-column-a-unique-data-in-column-b-i-want-one-row-for/998897#998897). Your requirements match this question exactly. You can accomplish your goals without VBA and just using formulas.

Comment: Hi Scott, this does exactly what I wanted but since my data in column A is dynamic and frequency of repeated values changes(goes upto 50 as well atimes) Hence Zack's option is the best suited for this. Appreciate you help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand why Tom gave you the advice he did. This wouldn't be a very good idea to get a recorded macro from because of the non-dynamic nature of recorded code as opposed to the dynamic nature of your data.

Here are two options. The first being what you asked for (run the 'PivotData_All' routine), the other being if you want to exclude non-unique items from the subsequent columns of data (run the 'PivotData_UniquesOnly' routine).

```
Sub PivotData_All()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Call PivotData(.Range("A2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row), False)
    End With
End Sub

Sub PivotData_UniquesOnly()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Call PivotData(.Range("A2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row), True)
    End With
End Sub


Sub PivotData( _
    ByVal IncidentData As Range, _
    Optional ByVal UniquesOnly As Boolean = False _
    )
'
' Take data from a given range and pivot out data based on first column being incident numbers, second column being
' measurement status. Each unique incident will be given its own row and the measurment status will be pivoted out
' along columns on a new sheet.
'
' Syntax:       PivotData(UniquesOnly)
'
' Parameters:   IncidentData. Range. Required. A two-column set of data. Left column is incident number, right column
'               is measurement status.
'               UniquesOnly. Boolean. Optional. Specify whether second column of data should contain only unique values
'               or not. If omitted False is passed.
'
    Dim Incidents As Collection
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Incident() As Variant
    Dim IncidentItem As Variant
    Dim IncidentTempValues() As Variant
    Dim IncidentStep As Long
    Dim IncidentMatch As Long
    Dim IncidentKey As String

    '// Change these as necessary

    '// Get values into an array to start
    IncidentTempValues = IncidentData.Value

    '// Iterate through array to get unique values, append all measurements to individual array
    Set Incidents = New Collection
    For IncidentStep = LBound(IncidentTempValues, 1) To UBound(IncidentTempValues, 1)

        IncidentKey = CStr(IncidentTempValues(IncidentStep, 1))

        If InCollection(Incidents, IncidentKey) = False Then
            Incident = Array(IncidentKey, IncidentTempValues(IncidentStep, 2))
            Incidents.Add Incident, IncidentKey
        Else
            Erase Incident
            Incident = Incidents.Item(IncidentKey)
            IncidentMatch = 0
            If UniquesOnly Then
                On Error Resume Next
                IncidentMatch = WorksheetFunction.Match(IncidentTempValues(IncidentStep, 2), Incident, 0)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
            If IncidentMatch = 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve Incident(LBound(Incident) To UBound(Incident) + 1)
                Incident(UBound(Incident)) = IncidentTempValues(IncidentStep, 2)
                Incidents.Remove IncidentKey
                Incidents.Add Incident, IncidentKey
            End If
        End If

    Next IncidentStep

    '// Put values into new sheet
    If Incidents.Count > 0 Then
        Set NewSheet = Worksheets.Add
        IncidentStep = 1
        For Each IncidentItem In Incidents
            NewSheet.Cells(IncidentStep, 1).Resize(1, UBound(IncidentItem) - LBound(IncidentItem) + 1).Value = IncidentItem
            IncidentStep = IncidentStep + 1
        Next IncidentItem
        NewSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End If

    '// Message user upon completion
    If Incidents.Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox "New sheet created ('" & NewSheet.Name & "') with " & Incidents.Count & " record(s).", vbInformation, "Complete"
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to create incident data.", vbExclamation, "Whoops!"
    End If

End Sub

Public Function InCollection(CheckCollection As Collection, CheckKey As String) As Boolean
'
' Returns True if the specified key is found in the specified collection.
'
' Syntax:       InCollection(CheckCollection,CheckKey)
'
' Parameters:   CheckCollection. Collection. Required. The collection to search in.
'               CheckKey. String. Required. The string key to search in collection for.
'
    On Error Resume Next
    InCollection = CBool(Not IsEmpty(CheckCollection(CheckKey)))
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

This would need to go into a standard module. Let us know if you need additional assistance with this.

Regards,
Zack Barresse

Comment: Thanks a ton Zack, this worked just as I wanted. The additional option gives a list of unique entries, awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This procedure assumes the following:

- Data ranges starts at `A1`, includes two columns and it's a continuous range of data (i.e. no blank rows in between, and column `C` is blank
- Output data starts at `D1`

  ```
  Sub Rng_List_Unique_Records()
  Dim vSrc As Variant, sKey As String
  Dim sStatus As String, aStatus As Variant
  Dim lRow As Long, l As Long

      With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
          Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1

          Rem Set Array with Source Range Data
          vSrc = .Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Value2

          Rem Extract Unique Items
          For l = 1 To UBound(vSrc)
              If vSrc(l, 1) = sKey Then
                  Rem Same Incident - Add Measurement
                  sStatus = sStatus & ";" & vSrc(l, 2)

              Else
                  If sStatus <> Empty Then
                      Rem Enter Measurements for Prior Incident
                      aStatus = Split(sStatus, ";")
                      .Cells(lRow, 5).Resize(, 1 + UBound(aStatus)) = aStatus
                  End If

                  Rem New Incident
                  lRow = 1 + lRow
                  sKey = vSrc(l, 1)
                  .Cells(lRow, 4) = sKey
                  sStatus = vSrc(l, 2)

          End If: Next

          Rem Enter Measurements for Last Incident
          aStatus = Split(sStatus, ";")
          .Cells(lRow, 5).Resize(, 1 + UBound(aStatus)) = aStatus

          Rem Output Range Columns AutoFit
          .Cells(4).CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit

      End With

  End Sub
  ```

Suggest to visit the following pages to obtain a deeper understanding of the resources used:

[Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html), [Application Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx), [Excel Objects](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Objects.html)

[With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx), [For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264596.aspx), [If...Then...Else Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251599.aspx)

[Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), [Worksheet Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194464.aspx)

Nevertheless let me know of any questions about the procedure

Answer (score -1):

It's been a slow day so..... This will do what you want using vba. You could also achieve this as Scott has said above with formulas or even using a pivot table. However by the looks of the question you're looking for something dynamic which will expand automatically to include new incidents which the formulas won't do easily.

I've over commented it in the hopes that you will easily be able to understand for future modifications. This is probably not the only way of doing it and not necessarily the best.

```
Option Explicit
Sub transposeAndCombine()
    ' Declare all of the variable names and types we will be using
    Dim inc As Object
    Dim c As Integer: Dim i As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim f
    Dim ws as worksheet

    ' Turns off screen updating - good practice for the majority of vba macros
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Declare worksheet
    set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Change Sheet1 to relevant sheet
    ' You'll also need to change all 4's that are detailed below to your relevant destination.
    ' I put all the processed data into Column D in my example
    ' starting from row 2 to leave a row for a header
    With ws
        ' Declare range that we are going to be considering (where the raw data is)
        Set rng = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
        ' Loop through that data
        For Each inc In rng
            ' Find if data exists in destination
            Set f = .Columns(4).Find(inc.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
            ' If it exists assign the row number to a variable, if not add it to the end
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                i = f.Row
            Else
                i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Cells(i, 4) = inc.Value
            End If
            ' find last column that has been used
            c = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
            ' add the Status value to the row
            .Cells(i, c) = inc.Offset(0, 1)
        ' Loop back for next data entry
        Next inc
    End With
    ' Turn back on screen updating for normal behaviour
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the input and helping me with the logice, appreciate your help a lot, However the code gave me no result. Even after I ran it, there was no response. Not sure why.

Comment: @Tony as said in the comments you'll need to modify certain lines for your workbook

Comment: My data is in Sheet1 and destination column 4 is fine. Anything else I missed that i should be changing in the code?

Comment: @Tony where is your raw data?

Comment: It is in Sheet1, Column A (Incident Number) and Column B (Measurement Status); With headers.

Comment: @Tony it's probably due to the fact that I've used the object name as opposed to the worksheet name. I've updated the code to declare it by it's tab name.